# Symbolic integral with UnitStep functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to symbolically evaluate the following integral (with real positive parameters `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, `La`, `Lb`, `Lc`, `a`, `λ`, and `ρ`):

```
P[J_, L_] := a*L*λ^(L)*ρ*L*Exp[-ρ*L*Abs[J]]

int = Assuming[
  Element[{La, Lb, Lc, L1, L2, L3, ρ}, PositiveReals], 
  Integrate[
   P[J12, L1]*P[J23, La]*P[J24, Lc]*P[J34, Lb]*P[J35, L2]*P[J46, L3]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J23] - Abs[J34]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] - Abs[J23] + Abs[J34]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J23] + Abs[J34] - Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J24] - Abs[J34]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] - Abs[J24] + Abs[J34]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J24] + Abs[J34] - Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J46] - Abs[h6]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J24 + Sign[J23 J34] (Abs[J34] + Abs[J23] - Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5])/2]-Abs[h4 + Sign[J23] Sign[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] ((Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] + (Abs[J23]-Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J46] h6]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J12] - Abs[h2 + Sign[J34] Sign[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] ((Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5]-(Abs[J23] - Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J24 + Sign[J23 J34] (Abs[J34] + Abs[J23] - Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5])/2] (h4 + Sign[J23] Sign[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] ((Abs[h3 + Sign[J35] h5] + (Abs[J23] - Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J46] h6)]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J35] - Abs[h5]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J23 + Sign[J24 J34] (Abs[J34] + Abs[J24] - Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6])/2] -Abs[h3 + Sign[J24] Sign[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] ((Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] + (Abs[J24] -Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J35] h5]]*
    UnitStep[Abs[J12] - Abs[h2 + Sign[J34] Sign[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] ((Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] - (Abs[J24] - Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J23 + Sign[J24 J34] (Abs[J34] + Abs[J24] - Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6])/2] (h3 + Sign[J24] Sign[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] ((Abs[h4 + Sign[J46] h6] + (Abs[J24] - Abs[J34]))/2) + Sign[J35] h5)]]
,{J12, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J23, -Infinity,Infinity}, {J24, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J34, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J35, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J46, -Infinity, Infinity}, {h2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {h3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {h4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {h5, -Infinity,Infinity}, {h6, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Running this code I never get an answer (actually I tried for something like 30 minutes without getting any answer, I guess Mathematica should compute it in few seconds). I tried to simplify the integral dividing the integration region in two: `J35<0` and `J35>0` so that `Sign[J35]` is `-1` and `1` respectively. I tried this strategy also for `J34`, `J23`, `J24` and `J46` together (getting a total of $2^5=32$ different contributions) but the problem is still there:  the integral never evaluates.

As an example I provide the following integral, similar but easier:

```
P[J_, L_] := a*L*λ^(L)*ρ*L*Exp[-ρ*L*Abs[J]]
I1 = Assuming[Element[{La, Lb, Lc, ρ}, PositiveReals], 
  Integrate[P[J12, La]*P[J23, Lb]*P[J13, Lc]*
UnitStep[Abs[J13] -Abs[J12]]*
UnitStep[Abs[J23] - Abs[J12]]*
UnitStep[Abs[J23 + Sign[J13*J12]*0.5*(Abs[J13] + Abs[J12] - h1)] Abs[h2 + Sign[J12]*0.5*(h1 - Abs[J13] + Abs[J12])]]*
UnitStep[Abs[J13 + Sign[J23*J12]*0.5*(Abs[J23] + Abs[J12] - h2)] -Abs[h1 + Sign[J12]*0.5*(h2 - Abs[J23] + Abs[J12])]]
, {J12, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J13, -Infinity, Infinity}, {J23, -Infinity, Infinity}, {h1, Abs[J13] - Abs[J12], Abs[J13] + Abs[J12]},{h2, Abs[J23] - Abs[J12], Abs[J23] + Abs[J12]}]]
```

Running the code for `I1`, in few seconds, I get the following output:

```
(24. a^3 La^2 Lb Lc λ^(
 La + Lb + Lc))/((La + Lb + Lc)^3 ρ^2)
```

As you can see in the last example I also tried to implement the UnitStep functions in the integral domains of the different variables. For instance `UnitStep[Abs[J46]-Abs[h6]]` implies `{h6,-Abs[J46],Abs[J46]}`, but for it didn't work.

Do you have any suggestion on how to compute the first one?

### Edit

The first integral is due to a problem in which I have these 11 integral variables: `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `J12`, `J23`, `J24`, `J34`, `J35`, `J46`, whose integration domain is the real line $\mathbb{R}$. I want to integrate the six functions of the type `P[J,L]`, as inside the `Integrate`, but only in a sub-region defined by: `Abs[J23]>Abs[J34] && Abs[h3+Sign[J35]h5]>Abs[J23]-Abs[J34] && Abs[h3+Sign[J35]h5]<Abs[J23]+Abs[J34] && Abs[J24]>Abs[J34] && Abs[h4+Sign[J46]h6]>Abs[J24]-Abs[J34] && Abs[h4+Sign[J46]h6]<Abs[J24]+Abs[J34]`. Since I didn't know how to implement this integrating region I used `UnitStep` functions, these are the first six `UnitStep` functions in the integral. The other six `UnitStep` functions are six Heaviside step functions which arise from my problem. To recap I have to integrate the six `P[J,L]` functions multiplied by six Heaviside functions (the last six `Unitstep` functions) over the region (identified before) on the space composed by the reals `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `J12`, `J23`, `J24`, `J34`, `J35` and `J46`.

I am referring to a problem of Classical Statistical Mechanics. The problem stems from the computation of the "response" function of a system of six Ising spins: "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6" (that is spin "i" can have only +1 or -1 values). The hamiltonian is:

`H[s1_, s2_, s3_, s4_, s5_, s6_] := -s1 h1 - s2 h2 - s3 h3 - s4 h4 -  s5 h5 - s6 h6 - s1 s2 J12 - s2 s3 J23 - s2 s4 J24 - s3 s4 J34 -  s3 s5 J35 - s4 s6 J46`

from which we understand that spin "1" is connected with spin "2" since there is `J12`, which is a coupling constant, and so on. The variables `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6` are external magnetic fields. Any of the 11 variables are random real variables and the functions `P[J,L]` are probability distributions. In this context I analytically found the expression of the "response" function at zero temperature (which should be computed in the region I mentioned before) and contains the last six `UnitStep` functions, since the response function I defined is zero or 1 at zero temperature, that's why `UnitStep` functions. That's why I needed this integral. In simpler cases, with less spins it is easy but in this case I don't get an answer.

Implement the region using the `UnitStep` functions worked for simpler cases (as the example I provided, which is similar) but not in this case.

Comment: What is known about the parameters `La,Lb,....`?

Comment: We know that all the parameters, that are `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, `La`, `Lb`, `Lc`, `a`, `\[Lambda]`, and `\[Rho]`, are positive real numbers. That's why I used the assumptions in computing the integral. I will add this info in the question, thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't assumption `Element[{La, Lb, Lc, L1, L2, L3, \[Rho]}, PositiveReals]` be much simpler?

Comment: Yes it is! I tried with that long series of assumptions and kept it, yours is much simpler. I will change it.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the UnitStep functions inside the integral domains? As you did for the second example? For instance `UnitStep[Abs[J46]-Abs[h6]]` implies `{h6,-Abs[J46],Abs[J46]}` and so on.

Comment: I tried to do something like you suggested. The problem here is that there are more variables and I didn't find a way to rewrite the whole integral to let Mathematica do it. I will write your suggestion in the question, thanks!

Comment: Why do we have to treat with such a mess code? Can you provide a minimal example of code with the same problem?

Comment: I do not actually know where the problem is. There are many variables of integration and many UnitStep functions but the whole integral doesn’t seem particularly complicated. I will try to simplify it and see if the problem holds. Then I will add this simpler case in the question

Comment: _the whole integral doesn’t seem particularly complicated_ ... it does to me. All the UnitStep stuff effectively does is define a complicated high dimensional indicator function on some region in some 5D space. If you can describe that region in a better way than using UnitSteps then it _may_ be possible to integrate symbolically. Otherwise, you'll have to provide some values for the parameters and use numerical integration.

Comment: It would help if you explained where all these UnitSteps come from... what overall problem are you really trying to solve by integrating this?

Comment: @flinty thanks for the comment, I provided the motivations. I am a newbie to Mathematica, so I could have used some complicated methods to compute something simpler.

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza I don't feel like you did, unless this problem is _synthetic_ just to test if you can integrate a difficult expression. The part you added on motivations just seems like a restatement of the question and is too abstract. I was really after the underlying problem in context with the subject matter, be it biology, quantum physics, whatever. If you are a newbie in Mathematica you may not realise there might be a simpler reformulation of your broader problem that doesn't involve doing this integral at all, but without knowing that it's pretty unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: @flinty I tried to add some informations but I don't think they would be helpful, to explain all the motivations I would need too space

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza do you _really_ need a symbolic result? Even if Mathematica could produce one, it would probably be hugely complex, slow, and unwieldy. `NIntegrate` might be more realistic.